# How to use vercel og image in next js app folder?

Tags: next.js, vercel, beta

But I am having trouble implementing ImageResponse to get returned as a NextResponse.

I have a question, I tried to implement the og image generation using @vercel/og inside app/somedirectory/route.js

But I am having trouble implementing ImageResponse to get returned as a NextResponse.

I am getting a error 405 or sometimes 500.

Any idea or code example about how to implement it properly?
I tried the following inside App/api/hello/route.js

```
import { ImageResponse } from '@vercel/og';
 
export const config = {
  runtime: 'edge',
};
 
const ogImage =  function () {
  return new ImageResponse(
    (
      <div
        style={{
          fontSize: 128,
          background: 'white',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          display: 'flex',
          textAlign: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        Hello world!
      </div>
    ),
    {
      width: 1200,
      height: 600,
    },
  );
}

export async function GET(request) {
  return new Response(ogImage)
}
```

It returned the whole function

```
function() {
return new _vercel_og__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ImageResponse(/*#__PURE__*/ (0,react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV)("div", {
    style: {
        fontSize: 128,
        background: "white",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        display: "flex",
        textAlign: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    children: "Hello world!"
}, void 0, false, {
    fileName: "C:\\Users\\.. ..test\\app\\api\\hello\\route.js",
    lineNumber: 10,
    columnNumber: 7
}, this), {
    width: 1200,
    height: 600
});
```

}

When NextResponse was used I was unable to get anything returned.
When I used the following

```
  const ogImage =  new ImageResponse(
    (
      <div></div>

     );

export async function GET(request) {
  return new Response(ogImage)
}
```

It simply returns [object Response]

Answer (score 2):

finally found out how to do it:

```
import { ImageResponse } from '@vercel/og';
 
export const config = {
  runtime: 'edge',
};
 


export async function GET(request) {
   return  new ImageResponse(
      (
        <div
          style={{
            fontSize: 128,
            background: 'white',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            display: 'flex',
            textAlign: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}
        >
          Hello world!
        </div>
      ),
      {
        width: 1200,
        height: 600,
      },
    );
    // return new Response(imageG);
}
```

This should be placed inside the :

> App/directoryName/route.js

This is so far the only way to get the imageResponse from an Api endpoint in NextJs new App structure.

[image: Next App Structure, with App directory, name of the folder 'Api' can be anything, it is not analogous to Pages/Api directory. It is just a route path, see nextjs v13 documentation about route path]

[image: Showing the code, where imageResponse being returned inside route.js]

[image: showing the generated image]

It is taking the request and returning ImageResponse.
If ImageResponse is stored inside a const and the const is returned with new Response(const), it will return [object response].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs 13 app router should be use
`import { ImageResponse } from 'next/server';`
instead of `import { ImageResponse } from '@vercel/og';`

I suggest you save your file as jsx or tsx to find out more from the error.

You may take the reference:
https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/og-image-generation/og-image-examples